# Proper way to connect to Socket.IO server using Golang

Tags: go, socket.io

I am learning Go and am trying to use [this library](https://github.com/graarh/golang-socketio) to implement a socket.io client in Go.

I am trying to connect from a client (written in Go) to a Node.js Socket.IO server. I have been having some issues with connecting to the Node.js server, the connection will always fail with "websocket: bad handshake" with no output on the server-side and none of the answers available on the web have given me a working solution yet.

I feel like I may have found the cause for my issue. From what I have read on the [NPM Docs for socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io):

> Note: Socket.IO is not a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds some metadata to each packet: the packet type, the namespace and the ack id when a message acknowledgement is needed. That is why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a WebSocket server (like ws://echo.websocket.org) either.

However, the socket.io client library I use (which is called `go-socketio`) only allows me to connect to a socket.io server using the `ws` or `wss` protocol, therefore it doesn't work and I cannot connect to my Node.js socket.io server.

**Is there a proper way to connect to a Node.js Socket.IO server from a Go-based client?** All of the articles I have read documenting this only show a Go-based socket.io server, not a client. I have tried multiple client libraries and none of them work (or they do not have enough documentation showing how to use the library as a client connecting to a server) :(

(I would be willing to use another bi-directional communication library which Go may have better support for as long as the serverside can be written in Node.js and allows the usage of Express.js alongside it as the rest of the server is written in Node.js and uses Express.js)

Thanks in advance and please inform me of any further information you may need to answer this question.

(I am currently not at home and thus cannot upload snippets of code, but I will do so once I get home)

Comment: would you be able to share the go-socketio client code

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the inconvenience!
I have found a solution. By using the [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package instead of the socket.io package for my server, I have got the Go client to work.

Thanks

Comment: can you please help me with getting started with websockets in Go?